# trying to alert random text instead of numbers

Tags: jquery, random

I'm doing a random generator that randomizes the different options you put in, I've tried to make it alert the number of the option which worked, but i want it to alert the text chosen instead of the number. This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#val').click(function() {
        var toAdd = $("input[name=message]").val();
        $('#messages').append("<p>" + toAdd + "</p>");
    });

    $('#kor').click(function() {
        var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * $("#messages>p").length) + 1);

        alert(random);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#kor').click(function() {
   var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*$("#messages>p").length);

    alert($("#messages>p").eq(random).text());

});
```

Get the element at that index, and get the text.

I also removed the `+1`, because `.eq()` is 0-based.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works almost perfect, but sometimes i get an empty alert-box, do you have any idea on how to solve it or is it something i did wrong?

Comment: Ah. `.eq()` is 0-based, so you need to remove the `+1`. See my updated answer. And, if it solves your problem, please [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) to let others know that this worked.